# How to mirgate code from developers instance to our sandbox

Tags: migration

A 3rd party development house has just completed some work for us in their development organisation and the metadata needs be to moved across to our full copy sandbox.

My understanding is that this can be achieved via:

- Unmanaged Package
- MetaData API
- ANT Migration tool

The work is pretty basic, 8 custom objects and some standard fields. No apex, automation or profile changes.

Can anyone recommend the best way to migrate this over?

I'm happy to skill up on whatever is needed but would really appreciate some guidance before I start.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case i would suggest to use unmanaged package to share with your sandbox as no apex class or code is there so no need to worry about code coverage while uploading package.

Answer (score 0):

You can use force.com IDE to migrate meta data from one org to another.

1. https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_Migration_Tool
2. https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Force.com_Metadata